# NextJS: Edit initial server log

Tags: next.js

When I start a NextJS server the following lines are printed on the console:

```
       ▲ Next.js 14.0.2
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000
   - Environments: .env.local
```

Is it possible to edit this output? I want it to have common used endpoints of my server so I can quickly call and test them during development. The output could look like this:

```
    Server started
    - Local:        http://localhost:3000
    - Environments: .env.local

    Here are some endpoints
    - http://localhost:3000/api/test1
    - http://localhost:3000/api/test2
```

Bonus question: Is it possible to have that output only during development?

Comment: I dont think you can edit the output, but you can customize you next.config to print something after  you run next dev